# Why did they air all four Tsukimonogatari episodes in one day?

Tags: anime-production, monogatari-series

The most recent story of the Monogatari series, Tsukimonogatari, has just aired and has all of its four episodes aired on one day. The same thing happened with Hanamonogatari which aired on August 6, 2014. They aired all of its five episodes on that day.

Why did they do that? Why didn't they wait and air 9 episodes over multiple days, or maybe wait some more to make Monogatari Series: Third Season with Owarimonogatari and Zoku-Owarimonogatari? Why did they air all its episodes in one day? What's the point of making it have 4 or 5 episodes when it could also fit in a movie as well?

Comment: The answer to "why 4-5 episodes rather than a movie" is, I think, straightforward - movies come with a whole host of challenges, e.g. fewer people are going to watch a movie than a TV special; there's an expectation of higher quality for a movie than a TV special; it creates a barrier to viewing future installments of the series (which is a big deal for Monogatari, since there are multiple installments still to come); etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason why Hanamonogatari was all aired on one day was because it kept being delayed because of production issues, it was supposed to come out the Spring season but ended up airing at the very end of Summer season (basically the Fall season). The studio decided to delay it no longer and release it all at once.

[See this ANN post](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/news/2014-05-13/monogatari-series-hanamonogatari-delayed-until-august-16)

I'm not sure of the exact reason for Tsukimonogatari's bulk airing, but it could be a related reason.

Comment: @nhahtdh I think in this case when we have a quote in a foreign language, we also need the English translation of that quote

Comment: @OshinoShinobu (and Kyouko) I probably have to remove the content I added, since it doesn't say anything about production issue. (The last 2 lines are "In order to deliver high quality works, our staff will continue to strive in production". The first 2 lines are along the line of saying sorry to fan for making them wait). The thing is, the MAL post doesn't cite any other source, so it is not too convincing.

Comment: I'm confused - is this the correct answer, or not?

Comment: @nhahtdh then I think you need to add another answer based on that translation because official website should be better source than MAL or Kyouko can edit this answer

Comment: I'll look for some other sources to confirm this (I'm pretty sure there are a couple).