# Why did ReLIFE release all its 13 episodes in one day?

Tags: relife

It's the first time I've ever seen an anime series that has released all its episodes in one day and not one episode every week, as it is normally the case.

Why did the producers do this?

Comment: it's not the first time ever happen. [Monogatari series has done this before.](http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/17272/why-did-they-air-all-four-tsukimonogatari-episodes-in-one-day)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think CrunchyRoll and other streaming companies are looking at the full-release model more now that it is a regular feature of Netflix.

Netflix has done a lot of internal work on retention analysis - both for keeping paid subscribers, and for series watchers themselves (as that will increase the subscribers' enjoyment and reduce their consideration to leave).  I couldn't find any figures on this, but I presume the drop-off rate of series is lower when episodes are all released at once - Viewers can watch more than a single episode in their first viewing, meaning they will be more involved in the plot by the time they next sit down to watch something.

The way the Crunchyroll model works, the episodes were only available to premium members during the first few weeks of release - this might have also convinced users to subscribe.

While Netflix has done this primarily to non animated works, Re:Life is not the first instance of this bundled release. [Voltron: Legendary Defender](https://www.netflix.com/ie/title/80075595) was released in this form earlier this year.